# Is there any specific difference between a "Christian" and a 'true' disciple of Christ?

Tags: bible, terminology, disciple

What is the Biblical definition of "disciple"?

Can you be "merely" a 'follower of Christ' or a 'Christian' and *not* be a 'disciple'?

Comment: Yes of course, but according to who? If you want specifics you _must_ specify what POV you want to hear from.

Comment: How do you define a Christian, and how do you define a true disciple?

Comment: @James - So far my definition of a Christian is this: the one who believes in the existence of only One God, who believes that God has the Only-begotten Son of God that is God Himself, who believes that one day the Son of God became a man Jesus that was born of a human mother Mary, lived, was crucified, resurrected and ascended, and the one who, while praying to God the Father, also prays to Jesus Christ, - this man is a Christian. As for a disciple - I have no idea. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: please let me know if my reword helps

Comment: Your idea of adding my definition of a Christian to the main body of the question is great, but changing the title from inquiring a difference between "a Christian" and "a disciple" to merely inquiring a definition of "a disciple" makes that addition senseless. So I will roll back the title.

Comment: @brilliant: In this case the "difference" here is irrelevant to the question, so the other title was better but your definition of Christian is also not needed. You could just as easily ask "my definition of a Christian is somebody who eats only red jam on their toast, what is the difference between that and the Biblical definition of disciple."

Comment: @Caleb - I myself don't know why the definition of a Christian was needed here. It's just that `James Black` asked me about it for some reason and `warren` decided to add it to the question. I though since he felt it was needed he might have some valid reason for that.

Comment: Pinging @warren -- see my other comment above as to why I don't think that's needed here, esp with your suggested title (which I support since the current one is half-off-topic).

Comment: @Caleb - how does that edition look?

Comment: A Christian is a follower of Christ. A disciple is a follower of a religion or belief system. Jesus had 12 disciples; Confucius had lots more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of a Christian seems a bit arbitrary, but one thing I notice is that the whole thing is based on beliefs.  But the word *disciple* comes from the same root as *discipline,* which suggests a few things as to its meaning.  Discipleship is not about belief, it's about what you do with that belief.

Much of the Sermon on the Mount, which lays out many of the core principles of the Law of the Gospel, is about self-discipline: controlling not only one's actions but one's very *thoughts*, not allowing anger to take over even when you've been wronged, etc.  And in [Matthew 16: 24](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2016:24) (and this is also mentioned in Mark and Luke) we see:

> Then said Jesus unto his disciples, If any man will come after me, let him deny himself, and take up his cross, and follow me.

So we see that following Christ requires *denying oneself,* (again with the self-discipline theme,) and *taking up their own cross.*  And this doesn't mean wearing a cross on a necklace!  To someone living under Roman rule, carrying your own cross was something that a prisoner condemned to death had to do, and the meaning here is clear. It's an extension of denying yourself: you need to be willing to sacrifice whatever is necessary, even your own life, in service to God's plan in order to be a true disciple of Christ.

In [Mark 10:21](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%2010:21), when talking to a righteous youth who professes a desire to follow him, Jesus gives a slightly different perspective on this:

> Then Jesus beholding him loved him, and said unto him, One thing thou lackest: go thy way, sell whatsoever thou hast, and give to the poor, and thou shalt have treasure in heaven: and come, take up the cross, and follow me.

Here we see the theme of sacrifice associated even more explicitly with discipleship and taking up one's own cross.  It's repeated even more strongly in [Luke 14:27-33](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2014:27-33), with a warning attached:

> 27 And whosoever doth not bear his cross, and come after me, cannot be my disciple.
>
> 28 For which of you, intending to build a tower, sitteth not down first, and counteth the cost, whether he have sufficient to finish it?
>
> 29 Lest haply, after he hath laid the foundation, and is not able to finish it, all that behold it begin to mock him,
>
> 30 Saying, This man began to build, and was not able to finish.
>
> 31 Or what king, going to make war against another king, sitteth not down first, and consulteth whether he be able with ten thousand to meet him that cometh against him with twenty thousand?
>
> 32 Or else, while the other is yet a great way off, he sendeth an ambassage, and desireth conditions of peace.
>
> 33 So likewise, whosoever he be of you that forsaketh not all that he hath, he cannot be my disciple.

Jesus makes it clear that he never meant for being a true disciple to be something easy.  It's much more than simple belief; it requires full commitment, self-discipline, and a willingness to sacrifice all that we have for his sake.

Comment: All true stuff here, it just picks up the story late and misses the first step. Also, what is arbitrary about that standard creed?

Comment: @caleb according to that definition Satan is a Christian

Comment: @Waggers: I sincerely doubt Satan prays to God the father through Jesus Christ. If you think he does I'm going to call that [citation needed]. In any event I wasn't trying to say it was or wasn't a complete or good definition, only that it the points therein aren't exactly arbitrary.

Comment: @Waggers - In my definition of a Christian, I meant "human" by the word "one". I have already changed it in the main body of the question.

Comment: @Caleb Praying=talking to. Certainly there's evidence of Satan talking to God (and to Jesus). Since Satan believes in the Trinity just as we do, he believes that in talking to God the Father he's also talking to Jesus.

Comment: @brilliant Thanks, that makes it a bit clearer. Although if ever a Satan-worshipper who believes in the Trinity talks to God, even to taunt him, they would be a Christian according to your definition.

Comment: @Waggers - Would a Satan-worshipper pray to Jesus? In my definition a Christian is supposed to do that.

Comment: @Waggers BTW, your formula "Praying=talking to" seems to me to be barely valid. If I am talking to my Mom, it doesn't mean I am praying to her. If the scribes and Pharisees talked to Jesus (mainly arguing with Him), it doesn't mean that they were praying to Him at that moment.

Comment: @brilliant According to Wikipedia (paraphrased), praying = communicating with a deity in order to form a rapport. Perhaps it's the forming a rapport that Satan-worshippers wouldn't seek to do

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1519/discussion-between-waggers-and-brilliant)

Answer (score 1):

In order to be a true disciple you must be called. It is the masters role to pick his disciples, call them to follow him and equip them for that role.

> **[Mark 1:17](http://www.esvbible.org/search/Mark%201:17)** (ESV)
>   And Jesus said to them, “Follow me, and I will make you become fishers of men.”

Those so called and equipped will go on to do the [things @Mason outlined](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3874/is-there-any-specific-difference-between-a-christian-and-a-true-disciple-of-chris/3878#3878). However just doing those things without having been called and equipped is a) impossible anyway and b) wouldn't make you a "true" disciple, just a mimic.

Answer (score -1):

The definition of "disciple" is one that is taught by God and it is the holy spirit that will teach you.

The definition of a "Christian" is to be *like Christ* When they saw the apostles doing miracles like Christ they call them "Christ like" which became Christians.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  When you get a chance, we recommend all newcomers visit the [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help), and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites).  Also, while I don't disagree with what you posted, I'd also recommend reading [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer).

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I also cleaned up your post a bit.